# How can I change time portion of DataTimePicker based on a variable?

Tags: c#

I have a `DateTimePicker1` in this format `"HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy"`

How can I save the value (Time) of mytime into the time portion of `DateTimePicker1`? I only want to change the time portion in `DateTimePicker1` and keep the same data.

```
DateTime mytime = Convert.ToDateTime( "14:53:00");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```
  var mytime =TimeSpan.Parse("14:53:00");
  var dp = new DateTimePicker();
  dp.Value = dp.Value.Date;
  dp.Value.Add(mytime)
```

Answer (score 1):

.net has special classes for date and time operations - DateTime and TimeSpan. let them do their job like this:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse("14:53:00");
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.Add(ts));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
yourDateTimePicker.Value = yourDateTimePicker.Value.Date + mytime;
```